# Laravel/Lumen - defining a relationship with parameters

Tags: laravel, orm, lumen

Consider a model *Employee* and a model *Project*

The *employees table* has a property **type** that can be assigned the following values "1", "2", "3", etc.

**Project hasMany Employees**

```
public function programmers() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Employee' )
        ->where( 'type', '1' );
} // hasMany programmers

public function testers() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Employee' )
        ->where( 'type', '2' );
} // hasMany testers

public function managers() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Employee' )
        ->where( 'type', '3' );
} // hasMany managers
```

**Instead of these relationships, I would want to have only one:**

```
public function employees( $type_id ) {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Employee' )
        ->where( 'type', $type_id );
} // hasMany employees
```

**It would work like this:**

```
$app->get( '/employee', function() {
    $project = App\Employee::find( 1 );
    return $project->employees( "1" );
} );
```

**However, I am getting the following exception:**

```
ErrorException in Response.php line 402:
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could not be converted to string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the contents of the error message:

> ErrorException in Response.php line 402:
>   Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could not be converted to string

The error is occurring in the Response class. The reason this error is coming up is because you're returning a **relationship** in your route definition rather than a **response**:

```
$app->get( '/employee', function() {
    $project = App\Employee::find( 1 );
    return $project->employees( "1" );
} );
```

A Relationship object cannot be converted to a string, and therefore the Response class doesn't know what to do with it.

If you want to examine the result of your relationship query in the browser, you'll need to return a [valid response](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses).

Try changing your route to something like this:

```
$app->get( '/employee', function() {
    $project = App\Employee::find( 1 );
    return response()->json($project->employees( "1" )->get());
} );
```

This will output the results of your query to JSON. Notice also the use of `get()`. This makes sure the relationship query is actually executed.

Comment: Thanks, also for the extensive explanation